# NUnit GUI throws System.AccessViolationException occasionally with our desktop application

Tags: .net, unit-testing, user-interface, nunit, devforce

(I opened this new question because this is about a desktop application, it's not ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC and we don't use MVCContrib, this phenomena is not .NET version specific.)
We use NUnit and Moq however and a bunch of stuff too like Unity, IdeaBlade, DevExpress, Crystal Reports just to mention some of them.
The symptom: only comes using nUnit GUI, and it's not predictable. Sometimes it doesn't come, but when something happens, lots of the test fail, for example:

`CompanyName.Shared.Services.Test.UnitTests.ApplicationServicesTest.CanLogin_WhenLoginFails_ReturnsFalse:
System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

If the system gets into this state, it doesn't even help if I close nUnit GUI and open it up again. The only thing which helps is to *reboot* the machine (!!! o_O).

Can it happen that this is some bug with the nUnit GUI itself? I'm just saying, because we have 8500+ tests and that makes up a *huge* treeview content! If all the tests run, nUnit consumes 2+ GB RAM, and consumes significant amount of handles (I'm talking about the Windows native handle 'resource').

I tried NUnit 2.5.3 and 2.6.2, both of them are affected.
Our solution was VS2008 for a long time and now it's VS2012. It doesn't seem to be dependent on .NET version either.

Comment: Snippet in code-base:
`
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr hProcess, int dwMinimumWorkingSetSize, int dwMaximumWorkingSetSize);
public void ReleaseUnusedMemory()
{
 GC.Collect();
 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
}
`
I removed the PInvoke, but it didn't get rid of the exception.

Comment: The -1, -1 parameters are special: they instruct the system to cut down the working set size to minimum. I think that's really bad, according to some old MSDN Win32 API pages it can cause the process to swap out of mem. Don't do such thing at home guys! It won't solve any memory issues!

Comment: Why this thing doesn't come when I run the tests from Visual Studio? It turns out that nUnit GUI and console runs in MTA threading apartment mode by default, while if I run tests from VS they run in STA. I annotated [STAThread] to some multi-threaded asynchronous test which were [Ignore]ed before cause they failed (only) on the server, but now they are fine.

Comment: Probably the AccessViolation exception has to do something with some native code somewhere. I'm sure there are other "sacrificing a goat" type stuff in the code-base like the SetProcessWorkingSetSize above (OK, I searched for PInvokes and didn't find too strange stuff besides that), plus we have many 3rd party dependencies like Crystal Reports. Sigh.